Chainlink Cross chain transaction getting reverted on source chain router call
If I set the below extra args on source chain contract:
    extraArgs: Client._argsToBytes(
        Client.EVMExtraArgsV1({gasLimit: 400000})

I set the gasLimit for function call on my contract as 600000.
Still my transaction gets reverted during this call
messageId = IRouterClient(i_router).ccipSend{value: fee}(
    destinationChainSelector,
    message
);

This is my failing transaction on sepolia source chain: 0x70999861d491297db22599dfa4c5954b3604c8a950318ff1010aea4fb6db03dc
Please help me figure out this issue.

Hi MAYANK, If you cannot successfully call function ccipSend, it usually because you are using the incorrect router address or do not transfer enough native tokens or LINK tokens into your ccip consumer smart contract.

The issue got resolved. I had to fund my contract with ETH. Thanks @Frank Kong

The issue got resolved. I had to fund my contract with ETH.

Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - From Review
